# Using Jest with Angular 13 + Clarity

Tags: angular, jestjs, vmware-clarity, jest-preset-angular

i am currently attempting to upgrade an existing Angular app which uses VMware Clarity.
I already managed to upgrade from 8.x to 10.x following the Angular update guidelines.
However beyond that the jest configuration breaks, as the newer Clarity versions and Angular 13 use esm.

So i tried to build a minimal working example to investigate the needed configurations.

Starting from the jest-preset-angular example app at https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/tree/main/examples/example-app-v13 , i added Clarity as described in https://github.com/vmware-clarity/ng-clarity/blob/main/docs/INSTALLATION.md#installing-clarity-angular-

The example app's `test` and `test-esm` run configurations in `package.json` work without problems.
But as soon as i add `ClarityModule` to the `app.module.ts` imports and run the `test-esm`configuration, the test suites for `app.component.spec.ts` and `app.component.router.spec.ts` fail with the same error:

```
ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down.
From src/app/app.component.spec.ts.
                                                                                                                                    
          at async Promise.all (index 0)                                                                                            
 FAIL  src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory,
 open 'C:\Users\NAME\IdeaProjects\example-app-13_test\node_modules\@cds\core\index.jsicon\shapes\times.js'

      at Runtime.readFile (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:2552:21)
          at async Promise.all (index 3)
```

The error happens immediately after adding `ClarityModule` to the `app.module.ts` without adding any Clarity elements to the example app's html.

To me the ENOENT part seems rather weird, as it looks like two paths for legitimate Clarity .js-files were intersected.

I tried various different combinations of adding jest.useFakeTimers, transformIgnorePatterns and other advice i found for similar problems, but these either did nothing or led to more errors. Since i am also quite inexperienced with configuring jest, I might also have used them wrong.

Could you please give me advice what might fix the above error?

The environment i am running this in is:

```
Angular CLI: 13.3.6
Node: 16.14.0
Package Manager: npm 8.7.0
OS: win32 x64
```

The versions of the Clarity packages are:

```
"@cds/core": "^6.0.0",
"@clr/angular": "^13.3.1",
"@clr/ui": "^13.3.1",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more debugging I found out, that Jest seems to have trouble resolving `ClarityIcons` while processing `node_modules\@cds\core\internal-components\close-button\register.js`.

So i tried adding various mappings to parts of `@cds/core` to the `moduleNameMapper` in `jest-esm.config.mjs` and finally succeeded in running the tests of the `jest-preset-angular` example app without errors. After eliminating the paths one by one it seems that adding the following mapping is sufficient for the tests to work:

```
"@cds/core/icon": '<rootDir>/node_modules/@cds/core/icon/index.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's failing your test and `Angular` with version 13 has by default  `ModuleTeardown` options enabled, I assume then disabling the teardown option in your `test.ts` could help.

```
getTestBed().initTestEnvironment(
  BrowserDynamicTestingModule,
  platformBrowserDynamicTesting(),
  { teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false } },
);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion by adding `teardown: { destroyAfterEach: false  }` in the `TestBed.configureTestingModule({})` options of the 2 failing test suites as the `jest-preset-angular` example app doesn't have a `test.ts` file. But sadly i am still getting the exact same error. Additionally i tried simply creating a `test.ts` , pasting your code and adding the imports, but it seems like the testbed is already setup before reading `test.ts` in this configuration, as I get an additional error  `Cannot set base providers because it has already been called`.